# Error while solving second order ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve numerically the following O.D.E

$$y''(x)+y(x)=a \frac{cos(x)}{30+y(x)^2}$$

with the boundary conditions of $y(0)=y(\pi/2)=2$.

I use `NDSolve` but can't trace the problem

here is my try

```
a=1;
NDSolve[y[x] + D[y[x],x,x] == Cos[x]/(30 + y[x]^2), 
 y[0] == y[\[Pi]/2] == 2, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

I believe its in the implementation of the boundary conditions, can anyone assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `NDSolve` syntax. In your case, it should be

> NDSolve[{eqn, bcs}, y, {x, x0, xf}]

```
a = 1;
NDSolve[{y[x] + D[y[x], x, x] == Cos[x]/(30 + y[x]^2), y[0] == 2, y[Pi/2] == 2}, y, 
{x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```